# how to capture all windows events on all open web pages

Tags: javascript

I am trying to find a solution wherein I could capture all the events happening on a browser and whatever user does is recorded. For example, if a user selects a text, I could create an event listener for that. This event listening is not restricted to a web page, but should be applicable to all open web pages. I don't know if it is possible with Javascript. Please answer if you think it is possible to record all the actions taken  by the user on a browser and create an event listener for a particular type of action(like selection of text) and make a record of it. 
    There is no relevant code for this question. I just need to know about the way with which I could         possibly create event listeners for a particular action happening in a browser(on all web pages).

Comment: This would be a massive security hole if it were allowed.

Comment: *There is no relevant code for this question.* That would be a problem, then. Given your specific requirements, you should give us *something* to work with.

Comment: I was only trying to find out if there is a way for this. If it is a loophole in security or no, I dont have any clue of it as I am very new in web development.

Comment: There is no code for this because I dont know how to do this.. If there is a way to do it, I could write something for it.

Comment: I am only trying to learn, my words might not be right but it doesnt mean that I am trying to barge any form of security anywhere. I dont think I should have been marked down like this.

Comment: And the better word for express my thought is how to use a browser extension. I didnt know that... I am very new to web development. Asking questions should not be a horror and people should feel encouraged to ask questions. I dont think students should ever be scared for asking questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JavaScript executing in the usual client side web development context (i.e. embedded in a page) cannot do this for obvious security reasons.

You would need to use a browser extension for this. Some browsers allow you to write extensions in JavaScript.

Comment: Thank you so much for the suggestion. I didn't know what were the right words to ask for this functionality... But your answer really helped.